# How can I delay monitor output?

Tags: macos, mac, display, high-sierra

Using Audio Hijack I can intentionally "lag" the audio, so that when a sound happens on the system, I hear it a second later.

[image]

Can I similarly delay monitor output? I want to have my display lag a couple of seconds behind the audio that I hear.

On my MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)'s built-in display.

Comment: I just wanted to mention it may be worth clarifying whether you're using an external display or a built-in display, as this may be relevant.

Comment: @Monomeeth MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)'s built-in display.